# Model property does not access in another model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, model-view-controller

I am trying to access another model's(`Property_Master`) property in current model(`PropertyDetails_Master`) for conditional validation purpose by inheriting `IValidatableObject`. But When I create object of another model(object of `Property_Master`), It returns null values of property. How do I get value of property of another model?

In my code

```
public class Property_Master : IValidatableObject
{

  //Another Properties

 [DisplayName("Property Type")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Select Property Type.")]
    public string PR_PropertyType 
    {
        get { return strPropertyType;}
        set { strPropertyType=value;}
    }
}
```

In another model, I want to use above `PR_PropertyType` for to check condition in `PropertyDetails_Master` model.

```
 public class PropertyDetails_Master : IValidatableObject
{
  Property_Master pm = new Property_Master();

    [DisplayName("Flat No.")]
    public string PR_FlatNo { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Floor No.")]
    public Nullable<int> PR_Floor { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("No. Of Bedrooms")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter No. Of Bedrooms.")]
    public Nullable<int> PD_Bedrooms { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("No. Of Bathrooms")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter No. Of Bathrooms.")]
    public Nullable<int> PD_Bathrooms { get; set; }

    if (pm.PR_PropertyType=="Flat")
        {
            if (this.PR_FlatNo == "" || this.PR_FlatNo == null)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("* Flat No. Should Filled", new[] { "PR_FlatNo" });
            }

            if (this.PR_Floor == 0 || this.PR_Floor == null)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("* Floor No. Should Filled", new[] { "PR_Floor" });
            }
        }



}
```

Now in above code when I check using debugger at `pm.PR_PropertyType`, it returns null. So, How can I access that `PR_PropertyType` property in `PropertyDetails_Master` class?

Comment: Because `pm` is a **new** instance of `Property_Master`

Comment: Can't we access `PR_PropertyType` using `pm`?

Comment: Of course not. You setting `pm` to a new instance, not an existing instance. Its unclear where your existing instance that your wanting to compare is. Does your view include both `PropertyDetails_Master` and `Property_Master`?

Comment: Yes, My view include both `PropertyDetails_Master` and `Property_Master`. How can I use existing instance?

Comment: Use a view model that contains all the properties you want. And rather than `IValidatableObject`, use a conditional validation attribute that implements `IClientValidatable` (e.g. a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) or similar attribute), so that you get both client and server side validation

Comment: Ok, I will try your suggestion.